# Why does this give a syntax error?

Tags: javascript, try-catch, hoisting

I was trying to understand hoisting from inside `try`better, so I made the following test case, but it throws a `SyntaxError`.

That's not what I was expecting.

```
console.log(x);
console.log(y);

console.log(z);

var x = 5;

try { var y = getY(); } catch(){}

console.log(x);
console.log(y);

console.log(z);


function getY(){
  throw "ERR";
  return 6;
}
```

Comment: and what is the error?

Answer (score 3):

The `catch` block should catch an error, otherwise it triggers syntax error. Try this:

```
try { var y = getY(); } catch(e){}
```

Also your `z` and `x` variables are never defined.

Comment: That was part of the test case! It was a control for the other one, for which the result should have been predictable.

Comment: I didn't understand your comment.

Comment: So the `var` statement will still be hoisted, despite being wrapped in the try block?

Comment: Yes, but you've only got the `y` inside `try` block. Your other two variables `z` and `x` are never defined, and yet you're trying to log them. If there is a global scope, you'll get values for them from global scope, otherwise you'll get `ReferenceError: x is not defined`

Answer (score 0):

The `catch` block needs an argument.

http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_errors.asp

Comment: Can you add code example and verbage to your description? Including a link is good. Examples are better. If you do, LMK...